# Python dictionary to handle large data

Tags: python

I would like to know how efficient is python dictionary in handling large data.
Lets suppose i have a two 12 GB files,can i create two dictionaries for each file where 90% of the data is unique in each file.And next i need these dictionaries for comparing data based on the keys.I tried on a 16GB machine where it was consuming all the memory and skipped executing script .Or any alternative to dictionaries in python ?
Below is the sample code

```
for line in fileinput.input(src_one,0,"",0,'r',False):
    line = line.strip()
    TmpArr=line.split('|')
    key=TmpArr[2],TmpArr[3],TmpArr[11],TmpArr[12],TmpArr[13],TmpArr[14],TmpArr[15]
    DictOne[key]=line
for line in fileinput.input(src_two,0,"",0,'r',False):
     line = line.strip()
     TmpArr=line.split('|')
     key=TmpArr[2],TmpArr[3],TmpArr[11],TmpArr[12],TmpArr[13],TmpArr[14],TmpArr[15]
     DictTwo[key]=line
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question, to get rid of all the basic typos/punctuation errors.

Comment: It would help tremendously, if you could specify what you want to achieve. Quite obviously, you can't put 24 GB of data into 16 Gb of RAM. But most likely, you don't need to do that. So specify what you want, then maybe someone can help.

Comment: @Unapiedra thanks for the comment ,i basically need to compare two files based on the 6 columns and write the matched records ,unmatched records from two files into another files.Yes obvious i cannot put 24Gb to a 16GB RAM ,but i would like to know is there any way or a python module to compare without having  everything  into the memory.Thanks

Comment: This sounds like something that could be handled better inside a database?

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries are not designed for out of memory data.

However there are standard libraries for this, namely the `shelve` module.